# Bootstrap cols behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout

We try to create UI component ICONS LIST which will be responsive using bootstrap cols classes (col-md-*...). 
The problem is when we trying to show same UI comp in different columns of layout 2:10 for example. 
The behavior (view) must be different... If this UI component sets inside of COL 2, then we want to see all icons vertically ( each of them separated by row), but when the component sets inside of COL 10, then we want to see that icon list in horizontal view.
Lets say that behavior of the UI Component must be dependent by it parent element, not by media tag. So what the solution we should use to get result ?

[enter link description here](http://minus.com/i/oB7F4pRq4T1p)

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the icons **fixed width** with **display inline-block** (or flow left/right).

The width has to be a little more than half of col-2 (so there will be no space for 2 icons in the same row)

This way, when the icons are in a narrow div (col-2), every icon will be on a separate row - i.e. displayed vertically; While in the wide div (col-10), they will be placed in a row.

Comment: Hi Greg. I think I understand what is your solution, but not in this scenario. I can't use fixed width and I have to USE the columns of bootstrap because of grid (based on UI). In bootstrap you have an option to give a different classes for each media device screen size (remember breaks?)... So I would like to use it. For example ol-xs-12 col-md-9 etc... Did you understand what i mean ? :)